# Mule http response builder 401 status

Tags: httpresponse, esb, mule

I'd like to return a 401 HTTP_response after a failed authentication.  I am trying to do this through the use of a http:response-builder component with the configuration below.  I don't care about anything previous within the flow, once it reaches this point all it needs to do is this.

```
<flow name="main" doc:name="main">
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
    address="http://localhost:8081/example" doc:name="HTTP" />
<byte-array-to-string-transformer
    doc:name="Byte Array to String" />
<cxf:proxy-service namespace=""
        service="" payload="envelope"
        wsdlLocation=""
        enableMuleSoapHeaders="false" doc:name="ProxyService"/>
<cxf:proxy-client payload="envelope" enableMuleSoapHeaders="true" doc:name="ProxyClient" />
<http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
        address=""
        doc:name="request" />
<byte-array-to-string-transformer
    doc:name="Byte Array to String" />
<logger message="The payload after the request is:#[payload]"
    level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
<choice doc:name="Choice">
...
<otherwise>
    <processor-chain>
        <logger message="Failed authentication is:#[payload]" level="INFO"
            doc:name="Logger" />
        <http:response-builder status="401"
            doc:name="HTTP Response Builder">
            <set-payload value="Authentication Failed" />
        </http:response-builder>
    </processor-chain>
</otherwise>
```

The error that I'm receiving through soapUI

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Could not find a transformer to transform "SimpleDataType{type=org.mule.transport.http.HttpResponse, mimeType='text/xml'}" to "SimpleDataType{type=java.io.InputStream, mimeType='*/*'}". (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException). Message payload is of type: PostMethod</faultstring>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>.
```

To me this says my current message is of text/xml, and it's trying to return a unknown type.  I've tried setting the content type of the builder to text/xml with the same results

Edit: The current status is HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

Many thanks for your time reading, and any replies.

Comment: Where do you see this error? Mule's log or as the HTTP response? What is the status code you're getting?

Comment: I edited for clarification.  It's the http response through soapUI and the current status is 500.

Comment: Actually we'll have to care about what's before (and after) in the flow because if I create a flow with an inbound HTTP endpoint and your `choice` above, I get the expected 401 response. So there must be something in the flow that prevents the response to be handled properly.

Comment: I added more of a complete flow to show inbound I have, what components and transformers I am using.  Hope this is more informative, and includes less assumptions.  The components are filled in, just not on here.  The payload looks normal going into the choice.

Comment: Aah CXF proxying... alright I have a solution for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the `http:response-builder` where you use it because its output will not be directly dealt with by the HTTP inbound endpoint but by the `cxf:proxy-service`. When the response is coming *downstream the flow* towards the inbound endpoint it hits the `cxf:proxy-service` which takes care of preparing the SOAP response: it can only deal with a message that has a SOAP payload and will control strictly the status code, overriding any attempt to set it up elsewhere in the flow. Moreover, in your case, you're building a non-SOAP response which will make the `cxf:proxy-service` even unhappier when it'll deal with the response.

So the trick is to separate the detection of the failed login from the building of the HTTP response, and locate the HTTP response building in the response phase of the flow. This gives:

```
<flow name="main" doc:name="main">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
        address="http://localhost:8081/example" doc:name="HTTP" />
    <response>
        <expression-filter expression="#[flowVars.authenticationFailed]" />
        <http:response-builder status="401"
            doc:name="HTTP Response Builder">
            <set-payload value="Authentication Failed" />
        </http:response-builder>
    </response>
    <byte-array-to-string-transformer
        doc:name="Byte Array to String" />
    <cxf:proxy-service namespace=""
            service="" payload="envelope"
            wsdlLocation=""
            enableMuleSoapHeaders="false" doc:name="ProxyService"/>
    <cxf:proxy-client payload="envelope" enableMuleSoapHeaders="true" doc:name="ProxyClient" />
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
            address=""
            doc:name="request" />
    <byte-array-to-string-transformer
        doc:name="Byte Array to String" />
    <logger message="The payload after the request is:#[payload]"
        level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
    <set-variable variableName="authenticationFailed" value="false" />
    <choice doc:name="Choice">
    ...
    <otherwise>
        <processor-chain>
            <logger message="Failed authentication is:#[payload]" level="INFO"
                doc:name="Logger" />
            <set-variable variableName="authenticationFailed" value="true" />
        </processor-chain>
    </otherwise>
```

Notice the use of a flow variable (named `authenticationFailed`) to control the response.

Comment: Solution is correct though, thanks for the explanation and the configuration.  It didn't cross my mind that the SOAP components were changing the response.  I'll need to take a closer look at what the cxf:service/proxy are doing then overall for better understanding.  I focused on the inflow for those pieces, and didn't look at the out-bound flow.